# Ubuntu 17.10 : How to get rid of the white box at top right corner of the terminal?

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, gnome-terminal

[image]

I changed my graphics driver from open source to Nvidia proprietary, and this white box appeared at the top right corner of the terminal, it doesn't go away with a restart, and my system runs slow with the open source drivers. The maximise, minimise, close buttons work though.

How do I get rid of the white box?

Comment: What driver version did you choose? Maybe try a different version...

Comment: Not sure how that box could have appeared when you switched the graphics driver. Anyway, the upstream bug causing that white box is https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/23, and while you can find a workaround in one of the linked bugreports, probably the easiest way to get rid of that is to upgrade to 18.04 which will be released in a couple of days.

Comment: Hey! I upgraded to 18.04 long ago, but today, suddenly this white box pops up again, it looks a bit different now. Also, the icons I use affect the size of the box. I have temporarily fixed it by turning on the application menu from gnome tweak tool.